# how to get the results from two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
  SELECT month,Avg(rain_fall) FROM rain_fall WHERE 
  STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01','-',month,'-',year) , '%d-%b-%Y') 
  between
  STR_TO_DATE('01-Jan-1991','%d-%b-%Y') and
  STR_TO_DATE('01-Dec-1993','%d-%b-%Y')
  group by month
  order by MONTH(STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01','-',month,'-',year) , '%d-%b-%Y'))
  UNION
  SELECT month,Avg(data_value) FROM temprature_data WHERE 
  STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01','-',month,'-',year) , '%d-%b-%Y') 
  between
  STR_TO_DATE('01-Jan-1991','%d-%b-%Y') and
  STR_TO_DATE('01-Dec-1993','%d-%b-%Y')
  group by month
  order by MONTH(STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01','-',month,'-',year) , '%d-%b-%Y')) ;
```

The above is my sql query. I want to get the average value against all months in a year of temprature_data table and rain_fall table for the selected years.

The error message received:

> #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

Use Parenthesis on each `select` query and `UNION ALL`:

**P.S.**: `month` is a reserved word. If here, you're using it a column name, try to change it to something else so it may not make a conflict in your later queries. [Check this list of reserved words in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

```
(SELECT 
    month,
    Avg(rain_fall)
FROM 
    rain_fall 
WHERE 
    STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01','-',month,'-',year) , '%d-%b-%Y') 
between
    STR_TO_DATE('01-Jan-1991','%d-%b-%Y') 
    and
    STR_TO_DATE('01-Dec-1993','%d-%b-%Y')
group by 
    month
order by 
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01','-',month,'-',year) , '%d-%b-%Y'))
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT 
    month,
    Avg(data_value) 
FROM 
    temprature_data 
WHERE 
    STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01','-',month,'-',year) , '%d-%b-%Y') 
between
    STR_TO_DATE('01-Jan-1991','%d-%b-%Y') 
and
    STR_TO_DATE('01-Dec-1993','%d-%b-%Y')
group by 
    month
order by 
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT('01','-',month,'-',year) , '%d-%b-%Y'))
);
```